# Is there a relationship between infinity norm (or any other norms) of a vector and the trace of its covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, norms

I wish to know if there is a known relationship between the infinity norm (or any other norms) of a vector and the trace of its covariance matrix?

I have found a paper [that used the following inequality for the estimation error covariance matrix in Kalman filter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.12473.pdf). This relationship can be found on Page 4 below Equation 14. The relationship is:

$$E(\|\mathbf{\hat{s}}(k)-\mathbf{s}(k)\|_\infty)\leq\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma(k))},$$

where $\mathbf{\hat{s}}(k)$ is the estimated state vector at time step $k$, $\mathbf{s}(k)$ is the actual state vector, and $\Sigma(k)$ is the estimation error covariance matrix. [The Kalman filter equations are taken from the original paper by Kalman.](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/fluidsengineering/article/82/1/35/397706/A-New-Approach-to-Linear-Filtering-and-Prediction)

I could not find any reference for this inequality.

Is this inequality a general relationship between a vector and its covariance matrix?

Comment: you should take the expectation value on the left-hand-side of your inequality; isn't this then just the statement that $\|x\|_\infty\leq \|x\|_2$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker 1- Are you saying that the trace of square root of the covariance matrix is the same as the 2-norm? 
2- What does expected value has to due with the inequality?

Comment: 1) yes; 2) just look directly below the equation 14 you are citing; the expectation value is there.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker 1) Thanks 2) yes, I missed the expectation operator.